# Website's table doesn't fit most resolutions

Tags: html, css

I've set our a box within my page. Within the box, I've got a table. On 1920x1080p resolution, the table looks like this:

[image: 1920x1080]

Whilst on other resolutions, it looks like this:

[image: 1440x900]

I've tried adding max/min widths for the table, but it still goes off-screen. I've done my research but all results don't help.

Here's my code:

```css
body {
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
 width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

li {
    float: center;
 text-align: center;
 width:10px
    border-right:1px solid #bbb;
 display: inline;
    list-style: none; 

}
li a {
    display:inline-block;
 text-align: center;
    margin-right: 0px;
    width:60px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#00742b;
    background-color:#f0bd00;
    text-align:center;
    padding:14px 80px;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #c49c00;
}


.active {
    background-color: #00742b;
 color: white;
}

#footer_menu ul {  
    padding: 10px;
    list-style: none outside none;
}

#footer_menu li.nav {
    padding: 0 4px;
}
.box {
 width:70%;
 padding: 0px 0px 420px 0px;
 background-color: grey;
 text-align: center;
 float: center;
 margin: auto;
 

}
.box2{
 text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title>4Late - Dynamic Estates</title>
  </head>
 
 <body>
<img src="dynamic_bg_logo_1.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:0;width:100%;"></img>
  
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
 <div style="white-space: nowrap">
  <ul id="footer_menu" style="text-align:center;font-size:100%;font-family:arial;">
   <li><font face="arial"><a href="index.html" style="padding-left: 40px;position:absolute;left:5px;top:5px;">LOCATIONS</a></li>
   <li class="nav"><font face="arial"><a href="newyork-city.html" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 35px;">ALL</a></li>
   <li class="nav"><a href="homes-and-appartments.html" class="active" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 170px;">HOMES & APPARTMENTS</a></li>
   <li class="nav"> <a href="offices-and-business.html" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 155px;">OFFICES & BUSINESS</a></li>
   <li class="nav"><a href="industrial-and-storage.html" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 175px;">INDUSTRIAL & STORAGE</a></li>
   <li class="nav"><a href="governmental.html" style="padding-left: 35px;padding-right: 105px;">GOVERNMENTAL</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
<img src="nav_underbar.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:0;left:0;top:11;width:100%;"></img>
<img src="white.png" style="position:absolute;z-index:-1;left:0;top:1;width:100%;height:1000px;"></img>
<br><br><br><br>

<div class="box" >
 <div class="box2" >

 <table border="1" width="100%" style="position:relative;">
  <tr>
   <td style="max-width:30%;"><p style="font-size:100%;color:#00742b;"><b>$$ PROPERTIES FOUND</b></p> </td>
   <td colspan="4"><p style="font-size:100%;color:#00742b;text-align:right;"><b>MURRAY HILL, NEWYORK MAP</b></p> </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="300px" height="200px" style="min-width:300px;max-width:300px;">
    <img src="property.png"></img>
   </td>
   <td width="50px" colspan="1" rowspan="3"></td>
   
   <td rowspan="3" colspan="3" height="600px" width="900px">
    <img src="murrayhill_default_map.jpg" height="95%" width="95%" border="2px" style="border-color:orange;"></img>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="300px" height="200px">
    <img src="property.png"></img>
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="300px" height="200px">
    <img src="property.png"></img>
   </td>
  </tr>  
  <tr>
   <td width="300px" height="200px"><img src="property.png"></img></td>
   <td colspan="2" width="300px" height="200px"><img src="property.png"></img></td>
   <td width="300px" height="200px"><img src="property.png"></img></td>
   <td width="300px" height="200px"><img src="property.png"></img></td>
  </tr> 

 </table>
 
 </div>
</div>

 
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are creating a website like it is the year 1990. Tables **should not** be used for creating the structure of a website. If you choose to continue, this problem will be the first of MANY. Learn how to use CSS and `div` elements instead.

Comment: Not just tables; <br> should also not be used for layout. Also get rid of the </img> end tags; they look silly. And a pet peeve of mine: you have errors in all your width and height attributes.